# sshfs command does not return

Tags: sshfs

I'm trying to mount the home directory of the login node of the batch system at my office on my local machine using `sshfs`. However, when I run

```
export LOGLEVEL=DEBUG3
sshfs remotehostname:/user/myname $HOME/mounted/loginnodehome -o sshfs_debug
```

I just get this as an output:

```
SSHFS version 2.8
```

and then nothing. The command does not return, and I get no further output. I assume I have misconfigured something, but I really don't know what that could be, and I would need some hints as to where to start debugging this. Any suggestions?

Details: My home machine is running ArchLinux, the remote machine is running SLC6. Both use zsh as default shell. I have configured passwordless `ssh` using the standard PGP key method. I'm ready to provide further details on request.

Comment: Try `ssh` or `sftp` to the same remote host, with `-v`. That will probably hang in the same manner as `sshfs` and for the same reason, and it will be clearer what the problem is.

Comment: Simply using `ssh` on the same remote host works flawlessly. About `sftp` I don't know, I've never used it. Could you provide an example command line to test?

Comment: `sftp remotehostname` is the command to test.

Comment: `sftp remotehostname` hangs. Authentication seems to work, but using `-v` the last line is `debug1: Sending subsystem: sftp`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved now. It was related to the `authorized_keys` file on the remote host, which read

```
command="/bin/zsh" id-rsa ...
```

Such that `sftp` and`sshfs` would try executing `zsh` upon login/authentication. Removing the `command=...` bit such that every line would start with `id-rsa ...` solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem. It turned out that I was trying to start sshfs, from inside a directory that no longer existed. That is, on the machine where I was running the sshfs command:

```bash
md -p /media/$USER/nomi && sshfs -o gid=$GID,uid=$UID nomi: /media/$USER/nomi
```

My current directory was inside a directory of a previously mounted sshfs, that ceased to be mounted. (I'm using `sshfs` to mount the hard drive of my laptop on my stationary computer, and the previous such mount got dismounted when I left my home with my laptop in hand. – Giving me trouble after having returned home with the laptop again, and trying to remount it.)

The solution in my case was simply to precede my the sshfs mount with a `cd` to my home directory (or any other, actually existing directory), like so:

```bash
cd
md -p /media/$USER/nomi && sshfs -o gid=$GID,uid=$UID nomi: /media/$USER/nomi
```